# Windows 8, Print to PostScript printer to file

Tags: file-io, printing, ghostscript

Am I missing something stupid simple?

I have a new Windows 8 machine... 64-bit.
From an app on my old machine, I generate report output to a "Generic PostScript Printer" which is configured to be sent out to FILE (not LPT, COM, TCP/IP).

While trying the app, it fails to generate the output to the text file provided.

So, I'm taking my application out of the equation.  I just go to control panel, pick this printer and tell the Windows printer dialog to do a test print.  It comes up with a dialog to enter the file name and I put it into a folder that I have full permissions to...  It fails... I even tried as "Administrator" to remove any possible "permission" issues and it still fails.

What am I missing on something that should otherwise be so simple, that even MS dialog / test print doesn't work.

---

```
To clarify what I DID do..
Control Panel - get to devices / printers
Add Printer -- clicked on the "printer not found"
Radio for "Add a local printer or network printer..." -- next
Use an existing port -- FILE: (Print to File)   -- next
Manufacturer - Generic  -- Printers - Generic XPS Class Driver (A) -- next
(used the driver already installed since I tried previously) -- next
Printer name: -- left alone by default of "Generic Color XPS Class Driver (A) -- next
Do not share this printer -- next
Print a test page -- dialog defaults to "Libraries\Documents\", I entered myTest.prn -- Save
It APPEARS to generate the file... however, it only creates the file as a zero-byte size
```

Comment: Are you using the Universal PostScript Windows Driver to install your PS printer?

Comment: @JScoobyCed, revised question with more specific detail

Comment: It looks to me very much like (as hinted at by JScoobyCed) that you are using the wrong printer driver. The 'Generic XPS Class Driver' produces, I think, XPS files, you want PostScript. When installing the printer select 'Microsoft' in the left column and 'Microsoft PS Class Driver' from the right column. When I print a test page this seems to work OK.

Comment: @KenS, actually, MS/PS was the first printer I tried and it failed too...  That's when I tried switching to an XPS/file-based output and got the exact same results... a zero-byte file.  Are you running Win8-64bit?

Comment: Yes Windows 8 64-bit version

Comment: @KenS, then I'm currently at a total loss...  This is brand-new, with exception to all security patches.  I'm not someone to go in and change complex settings all over the place and just get a zero-byte file.  I do get the file, but zero-byte size.  I also get a fail print if I try to generate the output file to other than the Libraries\Documents folder.

Comment: I generated mine to the Dekstop without problem, my installation is essentially clean, its very new and hardly used.

Comment: @KenS, thanks, I guess I'll just have to call M$ directly.  It shouldn't be that difficult, and mine too is virtually clean.  I've installed things like SQL, Visual Studio, but that should have no bearing on using a printer to file output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE... While digging and struggling, I actually opened a support ticket with Microsoft.  They have confirmed that this specific process IS a bug and will be working on a patch (to be delivered with other patches when ready).

ANOTHER UPDATE !

Apparently, the machine I bought from DELL only had Windows 8 BASIC version.  Through many support calls back and forth, it is a specific issue when trying to use certain printer drivers (such as Microsoft PS Color Printer -- for Post-Script output), from the default drivers provided with new machines with Windows installed.

OUR WORK AROUND.

For grins, I ultimately went out to HP's website (how common are HP printers :), and downloaded the printer driver for a 2500 LaserJet and install THAT version of PostScript printer.  After installing that, and trying the output, I can generate the output to a textfile without problem... even when default setting is to LPT1: and being redirected to an output text file for postscript content.

So, ultimately, issue resolved by using ANOTHER Vendor's printer driver for postscript printing and I'm good to go.